# Service hook url for teamcity from azure devops returns 404

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity

I want to create a commit hook for TeamCity. For that I've created Service Hook in azure devops:

```
http://teamCityServer/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(type:jetbrains.git,count:99999),property:(name:url,value:https%3A%2F%2FazureDevOpsServer%2FWeb%2FMy+Project+Name%2F_git%2FMyProjectName,matchType:contains,ignoreCase:true),count:99999
```

When I test a service hook I get an error 'Statuscode: 404'.
The problem, as I understand is with whitespace in reference to project. It is:

'*https://azureDevOpsServer/Web/My Project Name/_git/MyProjectName*'

I've tried both '+' and '%20' to create url-escaped link, but it did not work...

Any ideas?

Comment: This [blog](https://ifyoudo.net/post/2019/02/25/how-to-setup-azure-devops-to-send-commit-notification-to-teamcity) provides another commitHookNotification url format.You can try it to see if it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
http://teamCityServer/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(type:jetbrains.git,count:99999),property:(name:url,value:https%3A%2F%2FazureDevOpsServer%2FWeb%2FMy%2520Project%2520Name%2F_git%2FMyProjectName,matchType:contains,ignoreCase:true),count:99999
```

Hope this small change will save somebody's time

Answer (score 1):

Glad that Sasha solved the problem. I am here to add a troubleshooting to this type of issue.

It is recommended to try executing the following command from the command line before configuring the actual hook:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST "$SERVER/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=$LOCATOR"
```

If the commit hook matches the VCS root on the server correctly, you should see the output similar to this:

```
Scheduled checking for changes for 1 VCS roots. (Server time: 20160719T192540.787+0300)
```

If the commit hook has not found any VCS roots, it will report an error:

```
No VCS roots are found ...
```

Possible reasons for this output:

- the specified locator is incorrect, it does not match any VCS root on
  the server
- the specified user does not have enough permission for at least one
  of the matched VCS roots.

To check what roots are actually matched, use the request:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST "$SERVER/app/rest/vcs-root-instances?locator=$LOCATOR"
```

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.1/configuring-vcs-post-commit-hooks-for-teamcity.html#ConfiguringVCSPost-CommitHooksforTeamCity-Troubleshooting).